# Android - Using same dialog for multiple Views - trouble setting up

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext, listener, switch-statement

I'm having some trouble with a simple dialog i'm working on.  I have three different TextView's that when they are clicked I have a dialog box pop up with only the Title and one EditText.  I'm trying to make it so I use the same custom dialog for all three text views, but depending on which TextView is tapped the dialog set the new value to that TextView.  Below is my code:
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        super.onCreateDialog(id);
        CustomDialogPercent dialog = null;

```
    switch(id){
    case 1:
        dialog = new CustomDialogPercent(this, id);
        dialog.setTitle("Shipping Percent");
        dialog.show();
        break;
    case 2:
        dialog = new CustomDialogPercent(this, id);
        dialog.setTitle("Tax Percent");
        dialog.show();
        break;
    case 3:
        dialog = new CustomDialogPercent(this, id);
        dialog.setTitle("Commission Percent");
        dialog.show();
        break;
    default:
        dialog = null;
    }
    return dialog;
}

private void registerListeners() {
    shippingPercent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(1);
        }
    });

    taxPercent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(2);
        }
    });

    commissionPercent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(3);
        }
    });
}

public class CustomDialogPercent extends Dialog {

    int id = 0;

    public CustomDialogPercent(Context context, int id) {
        super(context);
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.basic_dialog);

        basicDialogEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.basic_dialog_entry);
        basicDialogEntry.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(true,true));


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        switch(id) {
        case 1:
            basicDialogEntry.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(basicDialogEntry.getWindowToken(), 0);                      

                        shippingPercent.setText(basicDialogEntry.getText().toString());

                        try {
                            if ((Float.parseFloat(basicDialogEntry.getText().toString())) < 0) {}
                        }catch(Exception ex) {
                            shippingPercent.setText("0");
                        }

                        mathCalculations();

                        CustomDialogPercent.this.dismiss();
                    }   
                    return false;
                }
            });
            break;
        case 2:
            basicDialogEntry.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(basicDialogEntry.getWindowToken(), 0);                      

                        taxPercent.setText(basicDialogEntry.getText().toString());

                        try {
                            if ((Float.parseFloat(basicDialogEntry.getText().toString())) < 0) {}
                        }catch(Exception ex) {
                            taxPercent.setText("0");
                        }

                        mathCalculations();

                        CustomDialogPercent.this.dismiss();
                    }   
                    return false;
                }
            });
            break;
        case 3:
            basicDialogEntry.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(basicDialogEntry.getWindowToken(), 0);                      

                        commissionPercent.setText(basicDialogEntry.getText().toString());

                        try {
                            if ((Float.parseFloat(basicDialogEntry.getText().toString())) < 0) {}
                        }catch(Exception ex) {
                            commissionPercent.setText("0");
                        }

                        mathCalculations();

                        CustomDialogPercent.this.dismiss();
                    }   
                    return false;
                }
            });
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

OK.  With this code what is happening is the first time I tap each TextView they work perfectly.  But once I tap any of them again the dialog boxes pop up correctly with the correct title, but values that are set back to the TextView are incorrect.

Example; i enter 8 for the shippingPercent and them 25 for the commissionPercent.  And then i go back to shippingPercent and enter 5. The 5 doesn't get set.  Instead it will be 25.  If i keep using the dialog boxes it seems like my mathCalculations() stops working aswell.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could assign a variable

```
activeTextView = theTextViewYouWant;
```

...then update activeTextView with the value you want?

Comment: I will try that. I am at work now, so I won't be able to try it until later.  Does the way I switch between listeners seem correct?

Comment: Your answer helped me part of the way.  I ended up using the "activeTextView" in my onCreateDialog in each switch and then i was able to take out the ridiculous switches I had in my custom dialog.  But after i did this i was still having the same problem were after i went through all the different TextView and then came back the a previous one it would apply the values correct.  What i ended up doing was in onCreateDialog in the switch I put "dialog = null" in each case before break.  This fixed my problem.
thanks, Kevin!!!